# How can I update a table with another table in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have two table say **A** and **B** of same MS Access DB.
I want to make table **B** fully dependent on table **A** so that any changes in table **A** should be reflected in table **B** in realtime.
How can I achive this.

Comment: It can be done using Data Macro (introduced in Access 2010), but it will slow down the system dramatically. It would be better if you describe the final goal, hard to imagine why this can be required for desktop database.

Comment: I have linked the access table "A" to the sql db. After linking a tabe with name "dbo_A" created in access. Now any change in "dbo_A" reflected in the linked table in sql db. But in my scenario the update being made in table "A" due to which the table in sql db is not updated. So how can I update the linked table in sql db by updating in table "A" in ms access. Also you can search question "How to get the realtime data into sql server database from a mdb file which update frequently?" asked by me for more detail.

Comment: Directly update the dbo_A table Use the linked table instead of the local table. The local table A is redundant. Why would you need both?

Comment: The local table is updated by third party only and they update it frequently (every minute). I am not authorised to update it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier and more resource conservative to just do your operations on a join - it would save space by not storing redundant data, and prevent any conflicts by having only 1 location that the value needs to be updated at any time. Perhaps I don't understand your problem very well, but this could be achieved by doing something like this...

```
SELECT colA, colB, ... colN 
FROM TABLE_A JOIN TABLE_B 
ON TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.id_from_table_a
WHERE <insert conditions here>;
```

Comment: I am having mdb file and want achive this in MS Access only without using sql db.

Comment: It's pretty impossible to achieve without some SQL or VBA. Please explain the purpose of duplicating the data?